# Como fechar uma duplicata exata em inglês?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, razões-fechamento

Está pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47193/apache-error-get-overlap-result-error está em Inglês e está a ser fechada como "Duplicata de " a sério?

Parece-me a mim que nem se dignam a ler a pergunta e fecham.

Answer (score 2):

Apesar de ser em inglês, era uma duplicata exata, postada inclusive pelo mesmo usuário. Do meu ponto de vista, os dois motivos de fechamento seriam válidos. Se fosse para eu fechar sozinho, talvez até optasse por duplicata mesmo, já que o fato de estar em inglês era óbvio, mas a duplicação não era.

Seja como for, pergunta excluída.

Comment: Mas como podes fechar como duplicata? E depois quem vier a procura no site da pergunta? Vai encontrar informação em Inglês? Não neste caso, mas em outros possíveis?

Comment: Como era uma repetição da mesma pergunta, com as mesmas palavras, feitas pelo mesmo usuário, o destino final deve ser a exclusão. O fechamento como duplicata me ajudou a chegar a essa conclusão. Se estivesse fechada como off-topic/inglês, talvez eu não reparasse, a menos que alguém sinalizasse.

Comment: Ora bem é bem visto nesse caso, mas acho que continua a ser errado fazer isso. Acho que deveria ser fechada como off-topic/inglês e depois sinalizada como duplicata. É, no mínimo, estranho termos uma pergunta em inglês marcada como duplicata, nem que seja durante umas horas até vir alguém apagar.

Comment: A não ser que a forma de proceder seja mesmo essa que indicaste.

Comment: @JorgeB. Pra mim tanto faz, contanto que ela termine apagada.

Comment: É meio que uma pergunta sem resposta, mas eu concordo com o bfavaretto. Marcar como off-topic e fechar seria uma reação muito extrema à uma pergunta que pode facilmente ser traduzida. Marcar como duplicata é uma maneira inequívoca de indicar que a pergunta não pertence ao site e deve sim ser fechada e excluida. Mas entendo o lado do @JorgeB... Qualquer dos dois caminhos é absolutamente válido. O atual só me parece menos esquisito (por incrível que pareça)

Comment: Pronto parece que sou o único a achar estranho assim, acontece ;)